# Add 'back page' to SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report with a grouped tablix, the group is set to page break between instances. So when I run it, I'll get one page for CustomerA, one for CustomerB, etc.

This is an invoice - the front page shows line items and customer details, the second page shows static terms and conditions. How can I insert a static second page between each customer's first page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Correct me if I am wrong.**

If I understand correctly, you want to have

> Customer A invoice (line items and customer details 1st Page, Static
>   2nd Page)
>
> Customer B invoice (line items and customer details 1st Page, Static
>   2nd Page)
>
> Customer C invoice (line items and customer details 1st Page, Static
>   2nd Page)

and so on.

For this, you can have a `list` grouped by invoices/customers whichever the case may be and the similar page break as you already have. And inside the `list`, you can have the your `Line Items and Customer Details Tablix`. Add a `page break after` in the tablix properties. Add the `Static Page Tablix/Rectangle` whatever you have right below this `Line Items and Customer Details Tablix`.